# For a given n,k find the sum

Tags: c

For given n,k find the sum 1^k+2^k+....+n^k: 
I compiled this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int n,k,i,j=1,t,s=0;
    printf("enter n,k");
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&k);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        t=i;
        do{
            i=i*t;j++;
            if(j==k)
            {
                s=s+i;
                i=t;
            }
        }while(j!=k);
    }
    printf("%d",s);
}
```

while compiling this I found no error in Ubonto Terminal. It asks n ,k . But no display. Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set j back to 1 after jumping out of the do-while

```
    [...]
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        t=i;
        j=1; //<---HERE
        do{
            i=i*t;j++;
            if(j==k)
            {
                s=s+i;
                i=t;
            }
        }while(j!=k);
    }
    [...]
```

I can't test this solution right now